# How can I get the correct output using the Auto threshold imagej Plugin?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, imagej

I have tried the following code, where I read an image from a directory and use ImageJ Auto Threshold plugin to segment my image. Any one can do that easily using imagej program as follow:

```
1- Open an image.
2- Then Go to : image->Adjust->Auto Threshold.
3- From methods drop list: Select the mean method.
4- Pick the white object on the black background.
```

My problem is I can't call this plugin correctly from Matlab. My Matlab code as follows:

```
javaaddpath 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\java\mij.jar'
javaaddpath 'C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\java\ij.jar'
MIJ.start

MIJ.run('Open...', 'path=[E:\\sun\\Endothelium Project\\Endothelium Code\\MIJ Code\\ENDOTHELIAL IMAGES\\12.bmp]');

MIJ.run('Threshold...','setAutoThreshold=mean');
MIJ.run('setOption=BlackBackground');
MIJ.run('Convert to Mask');    
SegmentedImage = (VorImage);
figure, imshow(SegmentedImage);
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on the error that you're getting?

Comment: The ERROR is:    Unrecognized command: "setOption=BlackBackground"

Answer (score 0):

**Auto Threshold** (in the GUI example) is a different command from **Threshold...** (in the Matlab code). You can see this if you use the command locator (press L, then search for Threshold you want).

So I'm guessing the syntax and options are different depending on the specific class.

I haven't used MIJ, but the `run()` commands look similar to those used in the IJ macro language.

When I use the macro recorder in Fiji I get the following:

*Image > Adjust > Threshold...* with Mean method, Dark background:

```
setAutoThreshold("Mean dark");
```

*Image > Adjust > AutoThreshold* with Mean method, no box checked:

```
run("Auto Threshold", "method=Mean");
```

Maybe one of these will work. In fact it looks like dark background is the default in the AutoThreshold command so maybe you could leave out that setOption entirely.

More on the threshold commands [here](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html#setAutoThreshold).